# Ambiance Theme Nautilus grey Files Selected

Tags: 11.10, nautilus, ambiance

I don't know if it's a clone of anything,but I still didn't really find an answer.
On Ubuntu, the Ambiance theme works perfectly fine, except on nautilus. Files selected inside nautilus show as grey, as if the window isn't focused, even when it is.[image: a focused Nautilus window]

The selection rectangle, however, retains the orange color[image: Selection rectangle in nautilus]

On the desktop, it seems to have the right theme[image: Desktop with selected files]

I tried other themes too, and the only one in which it doesn't seem to happen is Adwaita. Is it something in the theme itself then? How can I correct this? I can't seem to be able to find an answer.

-Amir
P.S. While these pictures are taken in gnome shell, the same happens under unity.

Comment: Have you found a resolve yet?

Comment: No, and I decided to leave it for a while when I didn't receive an answer, as it's not such a big problem. Still, it's odd. By the way, how do I repost? Are there any rules about that? Won't it be considered a clone?

Comment: lets leave it for a while longer - no need to repost

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Corrected in 12.04. Guess it was just a passing thing.